# windows 8 app with bing map connecting to multiple items from sample data source

Tags: windows-8.1, bing-maps

i am working on windows store app which will connect with bing map and show locations of each item individually data will be from sample data source as it is from default windows app and each item willhave longi and latitude and want to show map

Comment: And is there a question that goes along with that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should not try using the bing-maps on Windows phone 8, instead use the Maps API based on HERE maps. I have few examples that should get you started with this Maps offering at [Github](https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples), so check which one of those would suite your use case best, and start copying codes from them.

Also you might want to chek the [Guide to the Windows Phone 8 Maps API](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/guide-to-the-wp8-maps-api.html) documentation for the API.